Lua Scritp to detect Nmap scan
I was working with Lua scripts and trying to determine if there is any way to detect Nmap scanning using Lua scripts other than Suricata rules. What I've been able to deduce is to look for a particular IP that's been sending continuous packets on different ports and then generate alerts accordingly. Is there any other method that can be used to detect Nmap scanning besides relying solely on different flags?
I've searched for different available rules and scripts, but none of them are as efficient as they completely rely on flags. They can be easily misinterpreted. That's why I'm trying to build a Lua script that can detect Nmap scanning more easily and efficiently.
